# How to add a different webpage link to each set of data points on a Google charts scatter plot?

Tags: google-visualization

Is it possible to add the hyperlinks to the scatter plot, so when I click on a data point it opens the link?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I created a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cchana/EZbRY/1/) to show that it is possible to do this, but I couldn't find a way to do it in the way I would have liked.

After creating a data set, I created an array that has a list of URLs in the same order as the results that are displayed. When the select event is trigged by clicking on a point, a function is executed which in this case takes you to the correct URL.

Data:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Age', 'Weight'],
    [ 8, 12 ],
    [ 4, 5.5 ],
    [ 11, 14 ],
    [ 4, 5 ],
    [ 3, 3.5 ],
    [ 6.5, 7 ]
]);
```

URLs:

```
var dataUrls = new Array();                
for(var i = 0; i < data.D.length; i++) {
    dataUrls[i] = 'http://www.'+i+'.com';
}
```

(in this example, I've created a different URL that will be http://www.n.com for each result, where *n* is the index)

Once you've declared your chart, you can then add an event listener that will trigger when a point is clicked on.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    try {
        window.location = dataUrls[chart.getSelection()[0].row];
    } catch(e) {}
});
```

The important bit here is the `chart.getSelection()[0].row`, this tells you what result this is and gets the 'index' that you can use to retrieve the correct URL from the array.

There is a bit of a bug with this if you were to anything other than open a page in the same window. Basically, clicking on the same event twice throws a `TypeError`, which is why I've wrapped the call in a try catch statement.

As I said, there might be another way of doing this, but this but hopefully this a good starting point.